# Can't copy from clipboard to any Java applet

Tags: 10.04, java

The clipboard does not work with any Java applet on my install of Ubuntu 10.04. I am using the IcedTea plugin. I cannot copy/paste from Ubuntu to Java in either direction. However, IcedTea can copy to itself - that is, I can cut text from a Java applet and paste it into another part of that same applet. Other than this, clipboard support is fine across the rest of Ubuntu. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: Have you investigated whether a clipboard manager such as this question works for you?  http://askubuntu.com/questions/3335/why-might-i-want-to-use-a-clipboard-manager

Answer (score 6):

```
gksudo gedit /etc/java-6-sun/security/java.policy
```

and/or

```
gksudo gedit /etc/java-6-openjdk/security/java.policy
```

or (for example)

```
gksudo gedit /opt/java/64/jre1.7.0_04/lib/security/java.policy
```

Add the following line down the bottom before the last closing bracket.

```
permission java.awt.AWTPermission "accessClipboard";
```

If you are having trouble finding the correct `java.policy` file to edit, you can try to locate the file using

```
$ sudo find / -name "*java.policy"
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to brendan's answer, but the silly reputation system means I have to spam with a totally new answer...

On my system (Ubuntu 12.04 running Oracle Java 1.7.0_04), I had to modify a different file, with

```
gksu gedit /opt/java/64/jre1.7.0_04/lib/security/java.policy
```

Then, as per brendan's answer, add the following line down the bottom before the last closing bracket.

```
permission java.awt.AWTPermission "accessClipboard";
```

If you are having trouble finding the correct `java.policy` file to edit, you can try to locate the file using

```
$ sudo find / -name "*java.policy"
```

I experienced this problem on an embedded applet in Firefox, and had to restart Firefox after editing the file.

[Feel free to delete this if my edits to brendan's posts get accepted, but I also wanted to comment in his answer with my version of Ubuntu and Java.]

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem when copying text from Opera and trying to paste it in firefox and vice versa.  I solve this by opening the Text Editor and pasting in it.  Then I cut the text from the Text Editor and paste it in where ever I want.

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by brendan works, but it requires root access. To fix this issue with user rights, copy the file `/etc/java-7-openjdk/security/java.policy` to `$HOME/.java/` and change the following line before the last closing brace:

```
permission java.awt.AWTPermission "accessClipboard";
```

If you use a different java version than `java-7-openjdk` change the path occordingly. You find the correct path with `locate java.policy`.

Answer (score -1):

For Opera --> Firefox. You use any clipboard manager eg Parcelite.