# Why is Ubuntu's clipboard so hit and miss?

Tags: clipboard

I find that a lot of the time if I copy some text for example and then close the window being copied from, the paste function does not paste anything.

I've noticed this in Ubuntu 9.04 right up until present version. Is there a work around for this? Is there any reason why the developers are not looking into this?

Comment: Hah, that sometimes happens to me; usually only when I use the Right click -> "Copy", and then I paste, and there's nothing. -,-

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why might I want to use a clipboard manager?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/3335/why-might-i-want-to-use-a-clipboard-manager)

Comment: The reason is in @Oli answer - its a persistence issue - the workaround is to use a clipboard manager.

Comment: Yeah, as Dante points out in the other question, many consider this a bug.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why might I want to use a clipboard manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3335/why-might-i-want-to-use-a-clipboard-manager)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may want to review the Ubuntu Wiki's article on [clipboard persistence](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ClipboardPersistence), as it discusses the problem and how to get around it using clipboard managers.

This issue also happens to be a well-known, 7-year-old [bug on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/11334). If you have a Launchpad account and feel like it, you can go there and mark yourself as affected, though I wouldn't expect it to get fixed anytime soon. [This comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/11334/comments/16) on the bug explains why it exists from a technical standpoint.

Comment: Is there a clipboard application that doesn't sit in the notification area?

Comment: @Ants I don't know, actually, because I don't use a clipboard manager. To be honest, I don't run into this problem very often, and I just made it a habit for myself to leave windows open whenever doing copy/paste. If you're looking for a clipboard manager with specific requirements, you may try asking a separate question here for a [tag:software-recommendation].

Comment: @Switchkick If you use any dock (which uses dockmanager) then you can  use clippy, a cool clipboard for docky. [Sceenshot.](https://plus.google.com/photos/117696561634750603511/albums/5809982182996255873)