# Ctrl+C doesn't work in RubyMine IDE

Tags: shortcut-keys

I'm under Ubuntu 11.04 using RubyMine IDE.
I can't copy any text from this IDE by shortcut key `Ctrl+C`, in another applications it works well. The copy function from context works well in RubyMine.

Interesting fact that I worked with RubyMine under Ubuntu 11.04 as guest OS in virtual machine (Ubuntu was in classic mode). Shortcut key worked well there.

It seems to me that here's some intersection between Ubuntu's and RubyMine's shortcut  keys. How to detect this intersection and how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this question and see if the solution works - http://askubuntu.com/questions/61298/why-is-ubuntus-clipboard-so-hit-and-miss . It suggests you install `pacellite` ,suggested in the [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ClipboardPersistence)

Comment: Fixed, i've install ClipIt, it's a fork from pacellite. You should put your comment as answer so then I can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this question and see if the solution works - [Why is Ubuntu's clipboard so hit and miss?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61298/why-is-ubuntus-clipboard-so-hit-and-miss) . It suggests you install `parcellite` as suggested in the [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ClipboardPersistence).