# Does Ubuntu have a clipboard that works differently from Windows?

Tags: libreoffice, programming, bug-reporting, clipboard, data-loss

Does Ubuntu have a clipboard that works differently from Windows? I've noticed an anomaly between the two, perhaps a bug, or perhaps I'm misusing the functionality. It works the same way every time and leads to loss of data on my part, so even if it's me abusing the functionality someone ought to take a look at this.

I frequently open up a Writer program for it's spell checking capabilities, etc. (the Ubuntu I'm using came with LibreOffice), and now I've lost text several times because of this weirdness. I'm trying to train my brain not to automatically close the document after selecting Cut.

When I write something in LibreOffice Writer (either after opening a brand new document or an old one), and then select the text I just wrote, and then right-click, then select Cut, then close the document (yes, without saving), then try to paste somewhere, I invariably find that there is no content in the clipboard.

Is this a bug or does Ubuntu not have the Microsoft equivalent of a clipboard? if not, then what gives? Is copy paste only workable within certain data scopes?

The capability of copy pasting between programs seems pretty important. I've tested it out with one other program (Gedit), and it didn't lose the content. So I assume it is just a LibreOffice bug, as opposed to me misunderstanding the functionality.

Comment: Look at this question it is similar http://askubuntu.com/questions/61298/why-is-ubuntus-clipboard-so-hit-and-miss

Answer (score 2):

The problem with text vanishing from the LibreOffice clipboard in Ubuntu is discussed in some detail at this question: [Clipboard: vanishing text](http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/22703/clipboard-vanishing-text/) on the Ask LibreOffice website where David says in his answer:

> This is a system level issue, not to do with LibreOffice actually.

So you should either save your documents before you close them, or else leave the document open until you have made sure that whatever you cut has been pasted correctly. You could check your `/home/{your-username}/.config/libreoffice/3/user/backup` directory to see if you might have an older version of your document there.