# Why the clipboard gets erased when I quit the program?

Tags: lubuntu, 19.10, clipboard

I was trying to take a screenshot from my desktop, and decided to experiment with different programs. No matter what application I chose, the copied image from snapshot would get erased from clipboard if I closed the app. I've tried this with flameshot, spectacle, and looking back at this I know I have experienced this issue before with LXQT's default screenshot tool. How can I make this annoying issue go?

I am using lubuntu 19.10.

Comment: This is a known problem: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ClipboardPersistence

Comment: Have you tried saving the screenshot in a folder before closing the scheenshot taking program. Some of them have a setting to make this automatic.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli, if you would like to post an answer explaining that it's known, and not limited to KDE or Ubuntu 19.10, I'd vote for it, so it will show up in searches for folks who ask in the future.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/3335/why-might-i-want-to-use-a-clipboard-manager